# JavaFX write the input rows of a textArea to array

Tags: arrays, javafx, split, rows

I need to write every single row of a textArea into an array after I click a button. 
However, I have no clue how to seperate the the rows of the input text so i can write them to an array. (or if this is possible at all with textareas?)

Example:
Textarea:
line1
line2
line3

After I lick a button, it will generate this array of Strings:

```
array[0]: line1
array[1]: line2
array[2]: line3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
String[] rows = textArea.getText().split("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, does \n work for all operating systems? Sorry if thats a stupid question.

Comment: Yes: new lines are represented in a `TextArea` with `\n` on all platforms: assuming the user typed the text in. (If you load the text from a file, and the text file represents new lines in a different way, you may need to do some work to put the correct text into a text area, but that's a different situation.)